# Fragments being replaced while AsyncTask is executed - NullPointerException on getActivity()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-fragments

I recently converted my Activities to Fragments.

Using something similar to Tab-Navigation the fragments are replaced when the user selects another tab.
After the fragment is populated I start at least one AsyncTask to get some information from the internet. However - if the user switches to another tab just as the doBackground-method from my AsyncTask is being executed - the fragment is **replaced** and thus I am getting a `NullPointerException` in the marked lines:

```
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
  ...
  String tempjson = helper.SendPost(getResources().getText(R.string.apiid)); //ERROR: Fragment not attached
  ...
}

protected onPostExecute(Object result) {
  ...
  getActivity().getContentResolver() //NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION
  getView().findViewById(R.id.button) //NULL
  ...
}
```

`getActivity()` and `getResources()` causes an error because my Fragment is replaced.

**Things I've tried:**

- Calling cancel method on my AsyncTask (won't fix first error nor the second error if the fragment is replaced while `onPostExecute()` is executed)
- checking if `getActivity()` is `null` or calling `this.isDetached()` (not a real fix and I'd need to check it whenever I call `getActivity()` and so on)

So my question is: what would be the best to get rid of these AsyncTask problems? I did not have these problems using Activities as they weren't "killed" / detached on tab change (which resulted in higher memory usage - the reason why I like to switch to Fragments)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since `AsyncTask` is running in the background, your fragment may become detached from its parent activity by the time it finishes. As you've found out, you can use `isDetached()` to check. There's nothing wrong with that, and you don't have to check every time, just consider the fragment and activity life cycles.

Two other alternatives:

- Use Loaders, they are designed to play nicer with fragments
- Move your AsyncTask loading to the parent activity and use interfaces to decouple from the fragments. The activity would know whether a fragment is there or not, and act accordingly (by possibly discarding the result if the fragment is gone).

Comment: You should use isDetached() only if you explicitly detached the fragment yourself. Else, you should use isAdded() to handle cases where the system destroyed the link between your activity and your fragment.

Comment: @Nikolay Elenkov how life cycle can avoid checking everytime before calling getactivity?

Answer (score 4):

Today I've faced the same problem: when I changed the `fragment` being displayed if the `AsyncTask` has not finished yet, and it tries to access the `view`to populate it with some more elements, it would return a `NullPointerException`.

I solved the problem overriding one method of the fragments lifecycle: `onDetach()`. This method is called in the moment before the `fragment` is detached from the `activity`.

What you need to do is to call the `cancel()` method on your `AsyncTask`. This  will stop the task execution avoid the `NullPointerExecption`.

Here's a sample of `onDetach()`:

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    task.cancel(true);
}
```

Check this page to get more information about fragments lifecycle:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle
And this to view more about Cancelling a task: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Thank you, thank you so much. This fixed my problem that had been plaguing me for a week!

Answer (score -1):

Have you try calling `setRetainInstance(true);` in the `onCreate()` function of your fragment class?

Comment: This doesn't help in this case, issues are the same. For now I solved it by creating fields for the activity and view and setting them in `onActivityCreated()` by using `view = getView()` and so on.